# Content of form element not being saved to database while others are

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post, phpbms

I am working with a CMS like system, phpBMS, which defines a certain way of making forms, and defines the form elements to be used in such forms.

[This](http://www.phpbms.org/browser/trunk/phpbms/modules/sample/sampletable_addedit.php) is an example of the form template, and [these](http://www.phpbms.org/browser/trunk/phpbms/include/fields.php) are the fields that are defined.

Generally, it is pretty simple. If you have an inputField with the id of say, 'name', the content of that field will be saved to the name field in the table the form is assigned to.

Currently, I am using a different input field, inputSmartSearch, which works a bit like google suggest as it can search and automatically display results as you type.

I want to use the content of this field to go into a 'product' table, but I am unsure of how to set this up.

I am calling my smartsearch like so:

```
    $theinput = new inputSmartSearch($db, "chooseproducts", "Choose Product",$therecord["product"], "Choose Product", TRUE, NULL, NULL, TRUE, $required=true);
    $theinput->setAttribute("class","important");
    $theform->addField($theinput);
```

When I look what is returned by _POST, I see:

Array ( [chooseproducts] => 75c72a6a-83d9-11df-951a-fa9c1ec271f2 [ds-chooseproducts] => Corona [quantity] => 2 [type] => cash)

I have setup the quantity and type fields like so

```
    $theinput = new inputField("quantity",$therecord["quantity"],"Quantity",true, NULL, 1);
    $theinput->setAttribute("class","important");
    $theform->addField($theinput);

    $theinput = new inputBasicList("type",$therecord["paymenttype"],array("Cash"=>"cash","Credit"=>"credit"), "Payment Type");
    $theinput->setAttribute("class","important");
    $theform->addField($theinput);
```

The content of the type and quanitity fields get insert into the database perfectly, but absolutely nothing gets inserted from the smartsearch field.

Why? How would I start to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Just abandon this phpBMS thingy :) This is your 3rd post today about phpBMS problems. Or this is a viral-advert? ;)

Comment: It really shouldn't concern you how many questions I ask about a particular thing as long as they are all distinct.

Comment: @fabric haven't you ever been forced to work with something you didn't know well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case you would need to manually add this value to the array that is persisted to the database. So:

$variables["product"] = the value you want

So if you san. To persist the name assign Ds-chooseproducts. If you want to persist the id then use chooseproducts from the array.

Comment: I should add that you might not be able to put the name in the product field if it is expecting an int. But you will find that out once try it.